# Использование умных указателей

Tags: c++, winapi

У меня в коде часто повторяется фрагмент:

```
TCHAR text[10] = {};
Convert(window, id1, text);
```

Я его хочу вынести в отдельную функцию, которая будет возвращать указатель на `text`.

```
TCHAR* Foo(HWND window, int id)
{
    TCHAR *text = new TCHAR[10];
    Convert(window, id, text);
    return text;
}
```

Когда надо будет освободить память, мне не известно. Поэтому, я воспользовалась умными указателями:

```
std::shared_ptr<TCHAR> Foo(HWND window, int id)
{
    std::shared_ptr<TCHAR> text;
    Convert(window, id, text); //no suitable conversion function from  
                               //"std::shared_ptr<TCHAR>" to "TCHAR *"  

    return text;
}

void Convert(HWND window, int ID, TCHAR* text, int size=10)
{
    HWND handle = GetDlgItem(window, ID);
    GetWindowText(handle, text, size);
}
```

Как выделить память на 10 элементов и решить проблему с преобразованием?

Comment: Напишите `Convert(window, id, text.get());`. Но с выделением памяти это проблему не решит

Comment: Можете использовать функцию std::make_unique, как в этом [примере](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique). Но в любом случае обратите внимание на ответ alexolut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы `std::shared_ptr` правильно работал с массивами, для него нужно задать пользовательский *deleter*. Или, если Ваш компилятор поддерживает c++17, то можно параметризовать `std::shared_ptr` типом массива, например, `TCHAR[]` (спасибо за уточнение [GreenDragon](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/227465/greendragon)). Иначе в коде появляется UB, т.к. освобождение объекта будет происходить через `delete`, а не `delete[]` как это требуется после выделения памяти через `new[]`.

В данном случае общее владение в принципе не требуется, поэтому можно воспользоваться специализацией `std::unique_ptr` для массивов. Однако зная специфику Вашей функции `Convert` можно было бы посоветовать вовсе отказаться от ручного управления памятью и умных указателей в частности, и использовать `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`, например.

Т.е. я бы предложил переделать `Convert` как-то так:

```
std::basic_string<TCHAR> Convert(HWND window, int ID)
{
    HWND handle = GetDlgItem(window, ID);
    std::basic_string<TCHAR> ret(GetWindowTextLength(handle) + 1, _T(' '));
    GetWindowText(handle, ret.data(), ret.size());
    return ret;
}
```

Но может быть тут надо учесть ещё какие-то особенности *WinAPI*.

Comment: В C++17 для `std::shared_ptr` добавили специализацию конструктора для работы с массивами.